# what it the best choice for local caching in android?

Tags: android

I'm working on application that retrieve messages from some website and i want to cache these messages to not load messages every time ?

what is the best choice for storing messages locally??

Comment: idk, read the doc maybe ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest would definitely to store redundant data in some kind of `Map` (with limited entries).

For disk based mechanisms, Use a `SharedPreference` or even Sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

[SharedPereferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is the answer .Also do check [this data storage guide .](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)